# React Native with expo calling different page life cycle method

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native.
I have three screen in react native (home, profile, order) default navigation Home. 
On Home screen, it's calling componentDidMount of other screen as well.
and when I click on order screen then it's not calling.

Comment: Please post an example code that can reproduce the minimum problem.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake I was using creatematerialtoptabnavigator and forgot to use lazy